I can't count on my coworkers
I asked the people I worked with what 1+1 equalled.

Alice said 2
Bob wrote 10
Charlie answered 11

My final coworker tried to give me an answer as well, but I cut her off angrily saying I hadn't asked her.
Can you tell me what kind of job we all do?

Rot13(Qngn glcrf)?

huh? this was a fun puzzle, i dont understand why it was closed

Perhaps, you are all

Baseball players

Your roles are:

 Alice: 3rd base ($1_3+1_3=2_3$).


 Bob: 2nd base ($1_2+1_2=10_2$).


 Charlie: 1st base ($1_1+1_1=11_1$).


 Your final coworker must be the shortstop player, who isn't associated with a base. When they try to answer, you stop them short. (Thanks @Mike for pointing this out!)

Maybe, you are the:

 Pitcher, since you are pitching questions to your colleagues.


rot13(Sbe gur fubeg fgbc, lbh fgbc gurz fubeg.)

@Mike Brilliant!

rot13(Bar pbhyq nfx vs guvf dhrfgvba jnf pbzvat bhg bs yrsg svryq, ubjrire...)

@Mike rot13(Abg bayl gung, ohg gur fubegfgbc vf bsgra gur phg-bss zna jura na bhgsvryqre guebjf gur onyy vagb gur vasvryq.)

While this is nice, there are four more coworkers after the "final" one. And it doesn't explain why she had an answer to give, if she had been allowed.

Perhaps we're only fielding questions to rot13(vasvryqref). Maybe the rot13(fubegfgbc) was trying to give their response in base 2.5 or something

So Charlie is on 1st? ;-)

What if OP was just trying to say that the workers are simply rot13(ahzore onfrf, naq gurve jbex vf gb pbhag, naq gur ynfg jbexre vf onfr mreb)?


Computer programming


Alice is a non-tech.


Bob is speaking binary.


Charlie did string concatenation.


Final coworker is an optimizing compiler. She had the value calculated but didn't do anything with the result, so the calculation was removed.


But what about the last coworker? (right after the last bullet point)

Clippy: "It looks like you're adding two numbers. Would you like help?"

Alice could be the function that gets you that answer which also starts with an A, and I would guess the final coworker starts with D?

@rtaft "delete"?

I think you may be

 $d$its (base-$d$ bits), or else information theorists.


 Alice, Bob, and Charlie are the classic information senders/receivers in the context of information theory;

each person answers $1+1$ based on

 their status as bits: Alice is any unit of information of base $\geq 3$, Bob is a bit, in which $1_2 + 1_2 = 10_2$, and Charlie is a unit (unary bit), with $1_1 + 1_1 = 11_1$.

Finally,

 Eve, the eavesdropper, was not asked the question, but heard it anyway.


You could be

 Teachers in a school

Alice is

 Math teacher adding decimal numbers (1 + 1 is 2)

Bob is

 Informatics teacher adding binary numbers (1 + 1 is 10)

Charlie is

 History teacher adding roman numerals (I + I is II)

The final coworker is

 Biology teacher (1 + 1 make two and a half)

or

 Chemistry teacher (1 mol A and 1 mol B can become 1 mol C)


The idea for Charlie definitely doesn't work... those are 1's, not I's. And this answer doesn't really explain the behavior towards the fourth coworker.

@Sneftel I thought that the asker might have seen the Bees-and-Flowers answer coming and wanted to skip that for obvious reasons. The baseball answer has the same representation problem, that there are additional/different symbols involved.

The other answer doesn't have that problem: The coworkers are rot13(nyy gur vasvryqref), of which there are exactly four.

assuming the question was asked via text/email, its very easy to mistake a 1 for an I

@shieldgenerator7 The question was asked on this site. The font used, like virtually all fonts, makes the difference between I and 1 quite clear. (If you need, though, you can copy/paste the text into a text editor to see what it looks like with a different font.)

Industry:

 Software Development

Alice was using

 arithmetic addition, the kind we're all used to.

Bob was using

 arithmetic addition as well, but he gave his answer in binary.

Charlie was using

 string concatenation, treating the inputs as strings and just putting them next to each other.


What about final coworker ? And what about worker who asked ?

i took it as a reference to how badly women get treated

In my own experience women often are the heroines of Software Development

note that other answers have covered yours (and more) so I think it is hard to expect acceptance ... Have a nice day!

my answer is different enough from the other answers

This is my answer, without the final coworker.

@ralphmerridew I wrote mine before reading yours. my answer includes what kind of operations alice and bob did to get their answers, your answer does not
